# How can I close this search bar by also clicking outside of the container?

Tags: javascript, onclick, modal-dialog

I have a search bar that I built into the top of my site that opens upon clicking the mag glass icon.  I have gotten it to open via trial and error with js I have found online and I am also able to get it to close by clicking the X that is contained within the search bar display.  What I just cannot seem to figure out however is how to get it to close whenever a user also clicks anywhere outside of the entire search container called #jas-header .

The following are screen grabs of what I have.  The actual site is joriebreonn.com - it is live.

[image: open]
[image: closed]

The entire search bar up top is contained within #jas-header.

So I have found and tried to incorporate this into the js but have not had any luck bc I really have a less than minimal ability to write js but sometimes I get lucky and bits and pieces will actually work for me.  I have tried variations of, but with no luck:

```
      window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

and

```
$("body").on('click',function(){
   $("#jas-header").hide(); 
});
```

the js that successfully drives the box to open and close (the X is .sf-close) is as follows:

```
claue.HeaderSearchForm = function() {
// Open search form
$( '.sf-open' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $( this ).next().fadeIn( 0 );
    $( this ).next().find( 'input[type="text"]' );
});
$( '.sf-close' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $( this ).parent().fadeOut( 0 );
});
```

I just have not been able to successfully add to that to get it to return to default (image 1) by clicking anywhere outside of the search bar as well!

I tried to reproduce everything in a codepen but hah I couldn't even get my functioning code to work in the pen so I'm really at a loss.  Apologies for this likely being a very simple question for most of you but for me it seems just impossible!  Any help will be much much appreciated.

Thanks so much, Jorie. :)

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/focusout/ try 'focusin' and 'focusout' events instead of 'click'.

Comment: Hmm, thanks Ibrahim - that sort of worked - I replaced the '.sf-open' 'click' with 'focusin' and the 'sf-close' 'click' with focus out however now when I click the X the search bar does NOT close but lol it will close after I first click then X and then click anywhere outside of the search bar!  Apologies if this is very basic and I am not getting it - but is there a way to keep the X working all the time as well as being able to click outside of the search bar to close the bar??  And it's '.jas-header-search' I need to close not #jas-header.  Thanks so much! Jorie